# Submitting a form in new window with php

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Trying to submit a form with php.  When the form is completed and I hit "Submit", I want a new webpage to be loaded showing all the credentials and choices of the client along with a registration number for the client. I want to make the new page using an external .php file, using the "post" method.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="confirmation.php">

    What is your name? <input type="text" name="fullname" size="25" /><br />
    Your address: <input type="text" name="address" size="25" /><br />
    Your email: <input type="text" name="email" size="25" /><br />
    Your phone number (home/mobile): <input type="text" name="phonenumber" size="25" />


    What type of apartment are you willing to rent?:<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="1Bedroom" /> 1 bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="2Bedroom" /> 2 bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="3Bedroom" /> 3 bedroom<br />


    Rental Type:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="weekly" /> Weekly <br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="monthly" /> Monthly <br />

    Starting Date for Rental <input type="date" name="startingdate" size="25" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />


</form>
```

I have tried this so far (without the apartment type, rental type, starting date):

```
<?php 
 echo $_POST["fullname"]; <br />
 echo $_POST["address"]; <br />
 echo $_POST["email"]; <br />
 echo $_POST["phonenumber"]; <br />
?>
```

But the input from the forms is not coming through in the new window.

Comment: can you show what your <form> tag looks like? Also post your php code that handles the request, please

Comment: and I named my php file confirmation.php @binderbound

Comment: How do you mean in a new window and you just want to print the values from the form?

Comment: Yeah a new window will open with the values and choices from the form and a registration number. Eventually I'd like to create a text file to store all the information of the client. @Rizier123

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open new window upon submit. Try this

```
<form target="_blank" action="confirmation.php" method="post">

    -- Your code here --

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome. just hit like or choose best answer if my answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well It helped me out with the new window upon submit, but the php code is still not printing the value input from the form

Comment: Try this if(isset($_POST["fullname"])){ echo $_POST["fullname"]; }else{ echo 'fname is not set'; } then tell me what is the result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to get these values on `confirmation.php` with a redirect, and based on what you've provided you just need to fix your echos.

```
<?php 
 echo $_POST["fullname"]. '<br />';
 echo $_POST["address"]. '<br />';
 echo $_POST["email"]. '<br />';
 echo $_POST["phonenumber"]. '<br />';
?>
```

If you are trying to access these values somewhere other than `confirmation.php` you will need to use a session.

Comment: I fixed the coding up, but it still is not submitting the values to the php file. @EternalHour It just comes up as 

Rentals Name: 
Address: 
E-Mail Address: 
Phone Number:

Comment: @Sassn add the contents of your confirmation.php file.